# Async Javascript files that depend on order

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous, pagespeed

When using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Focr.pictures) to evaluate the performance of my site, I get a 70/100, and the recommendation is that I should make jquery and bootstrap.js asynchronous to improve the performance.

[image]

The problem is that asynchronous scripts are not guaranteed to execute in specified order. I had a problem earlier that the button to expand the navbar menu doesn't work if jquery isn't loaded when bootstrap loads.

How can I enforce jquery to load before bootstrap but still get the benefits of async scripts?

Comment: concatenate them in to 1 minified javascript file, in the correct order. this could solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at: http://requirejs.org. This will allow you to call on the js files you need for each page and it is async already.

Comment: Do not only look at requirejs - read this article: http://benmccormick.org/2015/05/28/moving-past-requirejs/ and then look also at http://browserify.org/ and http://webpack.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

It's basically saying your Javascript is being executed before loading the page, you can move the javascript to the bottom of your html (so it will be executed after the page is rendered) or use the defer attribute which is basically the same effect.

```
<script src="anything.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your jquery depended code with a function. And set an interval worker which would check if all dependencies have been loaded.

```
var worker = function() {
  if(window.jQuery /* and other stuff */) {
    dependenciesLoaded(); /* your app wrapper */
  } else {
    setTimeout(worker, 30); 
  }
}; 

worker();
```

Pretty dirty solution though. Look forward to bundle you scripts into one, or libraries with dependency management.